# Issue with iPhone5 UICollectionView.visibleCells index

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ios10, iphone-5

I'm having an issue with iPhone 5 specifically.  In my `UICollectionView`'s  `didSelectItemAt` function, I have this snippet which iterates through all visible cells, and stops at the first cell which has a nil `imageView.image`.

```
for cell in heroPickerCollectionView.visibleCells {

    let customIndex = heroPickerCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
    let nilCell = heroPickerCollectionView.cellForItem(at: customIndex!) as! HeroPickerCell

    if nilCell.imageView.image == nil {
        selectedHeroArray.insert(heroData.heroes[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row], at: (customIndex! as NSIndexPath).row)
        nilCell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: heroData.heroes[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].imageName!)
        checkForHeroes()
        break
    }
}
```

This works as intended on every device except iPhone 5.  On iPhone 5, the `customIndex` always starts `0, 3` instead of `0, 0` (as it should be).  Obviously this crashes because it attempts to insert at an index out of range.

I'm completely at a loss on this one.  `heroPickerCollectionView.visibleCells.count` returns the correct count on iPhone 5, but the indexes are off.

Comment: iPhone 5 device or iPhone 5 simulator?

Comment: It occurs on both